# Open Excel File on a specific worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel file with 5 worksheets and I want with c# code to open it 
and when it is opened I want the sheet number 3 to be activated.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to automate excel or do you want to display the data in a grid in your application? Or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like this:

```
 using Excel; 

 Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

  // if you want to make excel visible to user, set this property to true, false by default
  excelApp.Visible = true;

 // open an existing workbook
 string workbookPath = "c:/SomeWorkBook.xls";
    Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
        0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
        true, false, 0, true, false, false);



// get all sheets in workbook
   Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

  // get some sheet
 string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
    Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = 
        (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

 // access cell within sheet
  Excel.Range excelCell = 
        (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
```

Hope this helps

MDSN info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vbaxl10/html/xlmthOpen.asp)

Comment: it works only with .Visible = True. How about with .Visible = False?

Answer (score 4):

What about something like this: (untested)

```
//using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open("YourFile.xls", 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Number 3"];
worksheet.Activate();
```

Comment: Can someone please confirm @Denis

Answer (score 1):

If wanting to present visual feedback to the User, these two statements will set the activated sheet and select the range accordingly:

Consider including the following statement immediately prior to initializing the Excel.Range...

// Set Active sheet in Excel

excelWorksheet.Activate()

Also consider the following statement immediately after initializing the Excel.Range...

// Set Active range in Excel

excelCell.Activate()

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Workbook openExternalWorkBook(String fileName)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();            
        excel.Visible = false;
        return excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName, false);
    }
```