# How can I reference a different excel sheet every day?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook with 365 sheets, one for each day.
An employee adds information for the day on the corresponding tab and saves and closes it.

I want to create a new worksheet called current day which will display the most recently edited sheet.

The sheets are named by date so it could just call '9.11.2017' or it could call the most recently edited sheet.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "display the most recently edited sheet"?

Comment: When you save an Excel workbook, it remembers what the active sheet was.. so it's not clear why you even need to do anything to achieve this. And even if you did, activating today's worksheet wouldn't necessarily be the *last edited sheet*. Your question is unclear, as is the motivation behind it.

Comment: The sheet is displayed on a non-server instance of Confluence and the first sheet of the excel file is shown no matter what.

If I can make the first sheet just mirror the current dates sheet OR the most recently edited sheet, this would work the best.

Comment: I cannot fathom any possible reason for having 365 sheets. That is insane. It sounds like you're using Excel for something it isnt meant for.

Answer (score 0):

not sure to fully understand your question, but maybe you can consider to write code in the "Workbook_SheetChange" event in "ThisWorkbook" VBA module of your workbook file, so that you can track user's actions. Sample code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  Debug.Print Sh.Name & " - "; Target.Address & " - "; Target.Value
End Sub
```

This is if you need to track user's actions, i.e. last edited sheet: the Sheet name can be stored on a global variable, overridden each time this event is raised.
by using another workbook event, you can store the latest sheet name by writing it somewhere ( in a "log" worksheet, or in onother workbook)

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'... 
End Sub
```

Maybe it is not 100% reliable code, but it could work.

regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CD()
yest = Day(Date) - 1
m = Month(Date)
y = Year(Date)
sheetname = m & "." & yest & "." & y
Range("A1").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A1")
Range("A3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("A3")
Range("B3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("B3")
Range("C3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("C3")
Range("D3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("D3")
Range("E3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("E3")
Range("F3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("F3")
Range("G3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("G3")
Range("H3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("H3")
Range("I3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("I3")
Range("J3").Value = Worksheets(sheetname).Range("J3")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

I think it would be pretty straightforward to create a C# executable that would [open an excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012282/open-excel-file-on-a-specific-worksheet) spreadsheet to a particular sheet based on the sheets label and system current day.

The hard part would be hand writing 365 sheet names.  I guess you could write out the sheet with names, then read it using a similar algorithm.

Comment: What does C# have to do with that? It's even more straightforward to handle `Workbook_Open` *within the workbook* and `Activate` the correct sheet. Involving anything else is over-the-top.